# susy with Scout: can't configure Scout to require susy

Tags: sass, susy-compass

I've installed susy and checked it is present, I can create a new project using susy from the command line, but when I try to do this with Scout I hit a problem.  I add a config file which simply contains require 'susy' and put it in the Scout directory for the project and update the gui config to reference it.
When I start up Scout for the project which tries to @import susy, I get

"LoadError on line 1038 of org/jruby/RubyKernel.java: no such file to load -- susy"

Wondered if anyone had susy running on Scout and if so, how they set it up?

Answer (score 2):

ScoutApp does not support custom libraries (gem). All gems are bundled with ScoutApp and cannot be changed through the UI neither through a configuration file (eg. `compass.rb` or `config.rb`).

Actually, ScoutApp only [offers access](https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/blob/master/src/config/Gemfile) to [compass-960-plugin](http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-960-plugin), [yui-compass-plugin](http://github.com/chriseppstein/yui-compass-plugin), [compass-h5bp](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass-h5bp) and [zen-grids](http://zengrids.com/).

*Source: [Allow people to configure their own Rubygems](https://github.com/mhs/scout-app/issues/66).*

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to just pull down the Susy from Github - just the SCSS files. Put the susy directory in your project and import the main Susy file. Works with CodeKit (and even CodeKit Frameworks), so I think it should work just fine with Scout as well.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Scout-App comes with Susy mixins built in, however Scout-App 2 is no longer based on Ruby, so it does not support any Susy gems.

To use the Susy mixins that ship with Scout-App, just add any of these lines to your Sass:

```
@import "su";
@import "susy";
@import "susyone";
```

And it will import the code that is seen here:

- https://github.com/oddbird/susy/tree/master/sass

Latest version of Scout-App is available on it's site:

- http://Scout-App.io